I cannot import monsoon after installing Monsoon
I try to install Monsoon and then use it in the script, but I cannot import this module after installing it.
The Python version is 3.8.1; I also tried it in Python 3.11 and got the same issue.
Install script:
pip install monsoon

Then
import monsoon.LVPM as LVPM
import monsoon.sampleEngine as sampleEngine
import monsoon.Operations as op

Run the script, I got the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'monsoon'

What am I missing here or I need install it via another mode?

Update1
import monsoon and get the same issue.


Are you running your code in a normal or virtual environment? If the module has been installed correctly (which it appears is true) then the imposrts should succeed.

'import Monsoon...' should work

I am running the code in a normal env instead of virtual@OldBoy,

@ticktalk I tried import Monsoon and get the same issue, pls check the update1

It seems that the modules are filed under the name Monsoon with a capital M. So you need to change your import statements to import Monsoon.LVPM as LVPM import Monsoon.sampleEngine as sampleEngine import Monsoon.Operations as op. I have just tested this and it works successfully.

Hi @OldBoy, I am using windows, it seems not work, I try it via Linux, it works, form the answer, it seems that i need install Libusb first, I will try it and share the result help, thanks for your help

I did it in Windows with those exact import statements and it imported the modules successfully. If you are still having problems then please update your question with the exact details.

Monsoon - CAPITAL M ! , if you choose to ignore advice then you are going to struggle ., the 'import Monsoon...' where the '...' is 'as previously' shown meaning do what whatever your were doing previously with 'monsoon' just change it to 'Monsoon' ....

Yes, you are right, it needs Monsoon instead of monsoon, thanks for your help

As a Windows user, you need to install libusb. Monsoon library uses libusb to communicate with the Power Monitor. On Windows, this requires installing the libusb filter to allow the connection code to detect the Power Monitor. Instructions for this are available at http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html
See https://github.com/msoon/PyMonsoon

Thanks for your help, I will try it and share the result here. By the way, is anyway to found same demo about Power Monitor, I want to run some simple tests via script, thanks for your help again.

See if this helps https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.msoon.com/_files/ugd/b91e67_319f5400e3a04b7d885a6ee3544e8ea4.pdf%3Findex%3Dtrue&ved=2ahUKEwjAgoPUyY-HAxW0XUEAHcG_CFAQFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0DwSE6s4WESueBKBWYnCOh

I am check this doc, thx for your help

It seems tools issue, I tried to run it via cmd python main.py, or run it in the VS, it pass, in the PyCharm get the issue.
Note: The import cmd should be Monsoon instead of monsoon
